# How to run tests in StackBlitz?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, stackblitz, test-runner

Picked a sample React app on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-unit-test-ttuvmg?file=index.js). How does one run unit tests?

I see many people creating an app with tests, what's the purpose if those cannot be executed?

I guess you'd need a node.js project setup in order to run those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Available environments](https://developer.stackblitz.com/guides/user-guide/available-environments#frontmatter-title) documentation:

> There are two kinds of environments that run projects in StackBlitz: `EngineBlock` and `WebContainers`. Each project in StackBlitz is tied to one or the other.

From [Can I run unit tests in StackBlitz?](https://developer.stackblitz.com/guides/user-guide/general-faqs#can-i-run-unit-tests-in-stackblitz) documentation:

> It is also possible to run Angular unit tests inside **WebContainer-based** projects, but **not Engineblock-based** projects.

Your project uses the `EngineBlock` environment, you need to use the `WebContainers` environment.

You can see this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-5-react-starter-ahpjpn?file=.stackblitzrc), please note there is a `.stackblitzrc` configuration file to specify the start command. The `npm run test` script will be run after installing the dependencies.

```json
{
  "installDependencies": true,
  "startCommand": "npm run test"
}
```